# Wordpress - Mudei a estrutura de permalinks e os posts ficaram com erro 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: wordpress

Opa,
Mudei a estrutura dos meus permalinks para /blog/%postname% como na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O post abre normalmente, o curioso que no Google Console e no browser o erro 500 é sinalizado e aponta o erro no index:1 como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo e nada! Alguém sabe como resolver isso? É um erro de servidor ou em é no meu código/plugins?

OBS: em local o erro não acontece...

Comment: o post abre normalmente?

Comment: Abre normalmente: segue um post para acesso https://www.verdeghaia.com.br/blog/6-segredos-para-uma-gestao-de-requisitos-legais-campea/